# Android LunarLander example does not seem to use 'invalidate'

Tags: android

I am studying the LunarLander example in the Android sample code: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html

I am puzzled because the comments say in several places that the code uses 'invalidate' to trigger redrawing. But I can't find it in the code.

More importantly I believe that drawing should always happen in a View's `onDraw` and not inline elsewhere in a thread.

Has anyone studied that example and have comments about why `invalidate()` is not being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't inlined in a Thread but it is called from a Thread.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (mRun) {
        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                if (mMode == STATE_RUNNING) updatePhysics();
                doDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
            // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
            // inconsistent state
            if (c != null) {
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The drawing itself should always be called from a Thread when you do 2D graphics...

Comment: And thereby bypassing the built in window and view invalidation and android controlled redraw events?

Comment: It should be bypassed as the invalidate of even a not too complex layout can be really slow. It gives you the possibility to control what and when you want to redraw. If you need some entry points start with my tutorial series about 2d drawing: http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series